# insert half a million records using SQLite on Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm making an application that reads a file line by line and inserts the records into a database. The number of records is approximately half a million. The problem is that the whole process takes about two hours.

What can I do to speed up this process?

```
public long insertTable(int id,String word) {
    ContentValues wordValues = new ContentValues();
    wordValues.put(COLUMN_D, id);
    wordValues.put(COLUMN_WORD, word);
    return this.sqliteDBInstance.insert(TABLE_ENGLISH, null, wordValues);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate your sql statements within a **`Transaction`** and it will speed-up the database operations amazingly fast. Because when using SQLite Transaction, only single **journal-file** is created for the entire operation

Comment: Hello @Waqas please give some sample code or  a link to apply this technique.

Comment: http://simonwdixon.wordpress.com/2011/08/16/android-sqllite-tip-1-wrap-batches-of-writes-in-a-transaction/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [OrmLite](http://ormlite.com/)
it makes life better with sqlite
Hope that help

Comment: Or greenDAO, both should take care of compiled statements for you. greenDAO is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use [InsertHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.InsertHelper.html) and a transaction. The InsertHelper is very efficient because it uses compiled statements and you avoid object creation. Do this inside a database transaction, and it will be like 500 times faster.